# I need to dislplay indexOf integer array

Tags: java

I need help with `aslist`, `asList` gives me cannot find symbol. This is the code:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(array).indexOf(array[randomNumbers.nextInt(10)]));
```

I need to find the index of 3 random elements.

Comment: One of: `array`, `randomNumbers` is not known to the *compiler*. And we cannot say anything from the code you posted.

Comment: Add the mode code snaps and compilation error here

Comment: `Object[] array = new Object[1]; int i = ... ; System.out.println(Arrays.asList(array).indexOf(array[i]));` is working. Please check what the result of your `randomNumbers.nextInt(10)` really is.

Comment: And what is happening exactly???

Answer (score 0):

> Does our array[randomNumbers.nextInt(10)] return an int??.. Because this is what 
>   you are doing-

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(array).indexOf(array[randomNumbers.nextInt(10)]));
*******print list **get a list for array** get value from list where index= arr[randomNumber.nextInt(10)]
```

Your actual index for list will be array[randomIndex];

PS: I know this is not an answer... I found it difficult to post it as a comment..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you call `nextInt(int)` with an in not greater than the length of the array:

```
int arrayLength = 5;
Object[] array = new Object[arrayLength];
Random randomNumbers = new Random();
int i = randomNumbers.nextInt(arrayLength);
System.out.println(i);
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(array).indexOf(array[i]));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        /** your array declaration.. suppose array name is arr*****/
        List<Integer> mylist =new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arr)); 
        Random rndNum= new Random();
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            int k= rndNum.nextInt(arr.length);
            System.out.println(k);
            int j=mylist.indexOf(k);
            System.out.println(j);
        }
```